# Finding feet for desktop workstation mounted vertically

Tags: mount, desktop-computer, workstation

At work we have relatively slim (about 3.5" wide) Dell PC desktop workstations. These are placed vertically (on their sides) on the floor under our desks. They're not very stable, and a coworker knocked his over today (causing it to fail to boot).

I've seen L- or wing-shaped "feet" mounts or stabilizers for other devices - routers, game consoles, etc. Are inexpensive generic ones available for workstations, and if so, where? What are these called? (I've tried several searches.) Alternately, has anyone made their own from off-the-shelf materials?

Comment: This is why I don't allow my users to place computers under their desk next to their feet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something that looks like this (from [TigerDirect](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/category/category_slc.asp?CatId=1442&name=CPU%20and%20Printer%20Stands)):

[image]

or this:

[image]

You may find, however, that inserting CDs/DVDs may be a bit tricky.

Comment: +1 for the first option -- hanging the machine under the desk is much better than putting it on the floor. Less dust, less feet-kicking, less cables on the floor!

Answer (score 3):

Search for "computer stand" and you'll find lots of results similar to this 3M model:

[image]